# Get file from javascript

Tags: javascript, file, hyperlink

I'm not very familiar with js and now I need to do something very important for me, but I really don't know how to do it.
I'd like to include google translation api to my site, but I need to change some code in their js files. I have the element.js file on local host:

```
(function () {
  var d = window,
    e = document,
    f = ".",
    g = "UTF-8",
    h = "complete",
    k = "head",
    l = "link",
    m = "script",
    n = "stylesheet",
    p = "text/css",
    q = "text/javascript";
  Math.random();

  function r(b) {
    var a = e.getElementsByTagName(k)[0];
    a || (a = e.body.parentNode.appendChild(e.createElement(k)));
    a.appendChild(b)
  }

  function _loadJs(b) {
    var a = e.createElement(m);
    a.type = q;
    a.charset = g;
    a.src = b;
    r(a)
  }

  function _loadCss(b) {
    var a = e.createElement(l);
    a.type = p;
    a.rel = n;
    a.charset = g;
    a.href = b;
    r(a)
  }

  function _isNS(b) {
    b = b.split(f);
    for (var a = d, c = 0; c < b.length; ++c) if (!(a = a[b[c]])) return !1;
    return !0
  }

  function _setupNS(b) {
    b = b.split(f);
    for (var a = d, c = 0; c < b.length; ++c) a = a[b[c]] || (a[b[c]] = {});
    return a
  }
  d.addEventListener && "undefined" == typeof e.readyState && d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",

  function () {
    e.readyState = h
  }, !1);
  if (_isNS('google.translate.Element')) {
    return
  }
  var c = _setupNS('google.translate._const');
  c._cl = 'en';
  c._cuc = 'googleSectionalElementInit';
  c._cac = '';
  c._cam = '';
  var h = 'translate.googleapis.com';
  var b = (window.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://' : 'http://') + h;
  c._pah = h;
  c._pbi = b + '/translate_static/img/te_bk.gif';
  c._pci = b + '/translate_static/img/te_ctrl3.gif';
  c._phf = h + '/translate_static/js/element/hrs.swf';
  c._pli = b + '/translate_static/img/loading.gif';
  c._plla = h + '/translate_a/l';
  c._pmi = b + '/translate_static/img/mini_google.png';
  c._ps = b + '/translate_static/css/sectionalelement.css';
  c._puh = 'translate.google.com';
  _loadCss(c._ps);
  _loadJs(b + '/translate_static/js/element/main_se.js');
})();
```

(If it's important, link to this file from web page is "element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en" )

And I need to get main_se.js (the last link in the file) on localhost too, but I don't know how to change link in element.js to this file to make it local. I need it, because I have to replace some html tags in this file to make api work properly for me.

Hope that somebody will advice me what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `elements.js` produces a `<script` tag with `src` pointing to `translate.googleapi.com` and you want it to point to `localhost`.

The answer is quite easy in this case, simply remove the `b+` as `b` is `http://translate.googlapi.com` you will get the following script tag

`<script src="/transalte_static/js/element/main_se.js"></script>`

All you have to do now, it make sure you return the right file (your localhost copy) from this path.

Let me know if you need anything else.